# Anime/show about a giant robot shaped like a human with no hair in a red and white suit, that is controlled by a man seated within it

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, mecha

I remember this show vividly. I used to watch it on an old CD of my dad's and I don't remember the title.

All I can remember is a guy getting into a giant robot. The robot is shaped like a human with no hair; like just imagine a normally-built body, but giant man in a red and white suit. Anyway, what I can really remember is the way the guy gets into the robot; he gets dropped down into a seat where he can control the robot.

I think this show is just about fighting off enemies and so yeah, I hope someone will be able to help or maybe just one of you guys has a memory of what I'm talking about, and I apologize if I made any mistakes writing this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Live action? In Japanese? Anime? Was the red and white suit more like a superhero costume, more like a flight suit, or more like a business suit? Etc.

Answer (score 4):

The description of the robot makes me think of [Astroganger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroganger).

It was one of the first animes about giant robots, but the look of the main robot (the titular Astroganger) is very human-like, plus the colors (red and gray) could match with what the OP remembers.

The pilot (a kid) could summon this robot using a kind of medallion, then he would enter through a kind of tractor beam from the robot chest and drive it (though the robot has a kind of mind of its own).

It is of course very old, so I don't know if a DVD release exists.

In the [Italian wikipedia entry of the anime](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroganga) you can see a picture of the robot and its pilot.

Here is a video of the opening titles:

Answer (score -1):

Maybe *[Mazinger Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazinger_Z)*?

The description doesn't really fit for the shape of the robot and the suit, but the way the humans control the robots and the fact that it's a show about fighting enemies do.

Comment: This doesn't seem a terribly good match.